# Knockout bind to plain JS business layer

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

I've developed a library in TypeScript that performs calculations required for fitting Internet Spaceships.  The library itself is coming out great so far, but I am having trouble getting it to wire up to an interactive HTML UI.  I am trying to get it working with Knockout for now, but I am open to using another framework if it makes this particular task easier.

The specific problem I'm having is how to bind to a plain JS function result.  The initial page renders wonderfully with the initial appropriate value, but when I change a separate related field on my business object, the bound value doesn't update.

From reading into this, it seems that the way to fix this is either to:

1. Leave the library as-is and develop a viewmodel with Knockout observables such that the depended-upon observables are called as part of calculating the value.
2. Redo the library to include Knockout observables at the core.
3. Figure out some way to manually introduce a dependency matrix (essentially force-feed this info to Knockout).

I would really prefer to not do #2 as it seems like it's essentially an irreversible decision and I would like to keep the library as plain JS (TS) and separate from its UI as it could potentially be useful in node.js or other scenarios where Knockout is less appropriate (correct me if I'm wrong).

I couldn't find any info on how to do #3, but it's possible I just didn't get the right keywords.

So that leaves me with #1 where I had the not-so-clever idea of faking out Knockout by introducing a fake observable and a manual refresh method that the UI will have to call when it wants to refresh things.  #1 also causes me to have to basically write my library twice - once for calculating and once for presenting.

I mocked up a very simple #1 here: http://jsfiddle.net/wxks8/6/

example:

```
var myViewModel = {
    ship: ko.observable(theShip),
    seq: ko.observable(1)
};

myViewModel.refreshAll = function () {
    myViewModel.seq(this.seq() + 1);
};


myViewModel.shipStructureHP = ko.computed(function () { var x = this.refreshAll(); return theShip.structureHP(); }, myViewModel);

var myCode = {};
myCode.setSkills = function (theSkillLevel) {
    myViewModel.ship().pilot.skills.SetAllSkills(theSkillLevel);
    myViewModel.refreshAll();
}
```

In the above example, the shipStructureHP() ko.computed function calls the RefreshAll method which Knockout knows uses the "Seq" observable.  This means that knockout will record shipStructureHP() as dependent on Seq, therefore any time I increment Seq, elements bound to shipStructureHP() should re-render.

This feels like a major hack so I can't imagine I'm doing the right thing here (nevermind the bug where it calls refresh multiple times).

I don't need to support legacy browsers so if converting functions to ES5 properties would help, I can do that.  I'm open to any suggestions on how to get Knockout (or similar library) to do this databinding while leaving my business library as plain JS.  Is there a better way to do this than my fake dependency idea?  Preferably something that doesn't require me to duplicate large portions of the business library in the UI just to get a bindable viewmodel.

Thanks.

Comment: For clarification, are you trying to update the JS business model when the UI observables change; update the UI observables when the buisness model changes, or both?  If it's only the first you need to worry about, it's not too bad.  But, yeah, getting your ko observables to "observe" non-observables is hard.

Comment: It varies throughout the model.  Internet Spaceships can have different modules added or removed in different slots and the pilot flying the ship can have varying levels of skill in different areas.  These things would need to have "two-way binding" with the UI, but that's not the tricky part.  "I am fitting this afterburner in this ship fitting slot, therefore this element in this array will change so it contains the ID of that module" is mostly straight forward.  The part I'm asking about is "how do I get the max velocity on the ship (a plain JS function) to know to recalculate itself?"

Comment: Have you looked into using observable.subscribe?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I did just look into that as well as knockout.mapping, knockout.viewmodel, and knockout.wrap.  None of these quite seemed to fix my problem.  I was able to find a possibly working solution with Angular which I'm going to explore further.

Comment: Have you looked at the knockout es5 plugin?  http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/05/20/knockout-es5-a-plugin-to-simplify-your-syntax/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I did actually see that library and attempt to use it at some point after asking this question.  As it turns out, the browser in the Eve client is a fork of Chromium 3 which doesn't support ES5 getters and setters.  So in the end, the basis of the question is incorrect and I need a solution that works with ES3.  I am going to just delete this question in a day or so as I don't think this is possible with my set of requirements and I've pretty much just settled on brute forcing a dependency matrix inside an exhaustive duplicative viewmodel.  Thanks very much.